# Vim - difference betwen colon and Q

Tags: vim

So why are there two version of inputting ex commands?

```
:
```

and

```
Q
```

I imagine Q is used for backward compatibility, as it is also present in vi, but then why would vim use the colon? Instead of using the colon, why doesn't it create a buffer for ex, which could be accessed by typing `qQ`(instead of `q:`)?

Is there a good purpose for this(apparent) duplication?

Comment: difference betw Q and ":" has been explained in help doc, right? `:h Q`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `:help Q` explains this well:

> Switch to "Ex" mode.  This is a bit like typing ":"
>   commands one after another, except:

One usually types only a single Ex command (or chains then with `:cmd1 | cmd2`), so this mode isn't really helpful.

> - You don't have to keep pressing ":".

Not much of a benefit.

> - The screen doesn't get updated after each command.

You see the old Ex behavior in here: Printing of lines has to be explicitly requested. Useful (to save paper) in the teletype age, not today.

> - There is no normal command-line editing.
> - Mappings and abbreviations are not used.

Huge downsides.

#### Summary

Overall, this is only included for backward compatibility with vi; I don't think anybody uses it. vi itself leveraged ex, so it's not surprising that some inconsistencies and rough edges persist until today.